# Getting Route from URL in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

I recently updated a project from Laravel 5.4, to 9.X using Laravel shift.

I had a language controller that would allow me to swap language, and it would also translate my URLs.

It seems like this doesn't work anymore:

```
$route = app('router')->getRoutes()->match(app('request')->create($previous_request->getUri()));
```

Actually, I did something like this before, but neither work

```
$route_name = app('router')->getRoutes()->match($previous_request)->getName();
```

By not work, I mean, if I debug like this:

```
Log::debug("URL: " . $previous_request->getUri());
$route = app('router')->getRoutes()->match(app('request')->create($previous_request->getUri()));
Log::debug('Route: ' . $route);
```

laravel.log will containt URL: and the correct url, but Route: never shows up.

Did I miss some breaking change going from 5.4 to 9.X? How would I now get the route from an url?

Comment: What do you expect the "`Log::debug('Route: ' . $route);`" line to output? `$route` is an object, and you are concating it with `string`.

Comment: Well, even so, I would expect it to log "Route: " and then nothing. But it's not even doing that. It's like it stops running from that point.

Comment: Yes, because of error not event "Route: " will print; reproduce in terminal: ```php -r "class MyClass {public $uri;} echo 'Route: ' . new MyClass();"```

Answer (score 0):

```
My Current URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/list
```

```
$currentRouteName = Route::currentRouteName();
dd($currentRouteName);
```

```
Output: users.list
```

```
$currentRouteAction = Route::currentRouteAction();
dd($currentRouteAction);
```

```
Output: App\Http\Controllers\UserController@userLists
```